# PtrSafe VBA - updating an Excel document for Office 64-bit

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently updating a document for our company that no longer runs when used on a 64bit Microsoft Office suite (32bit remains fine).

I understand that functions and declarations require the 'Ptrsafe' word to be added - but when I add it to this function it tells me the syntax is wrong

```
Private PtrSafe Function executeSingle(Optional rurl As String = vbNullString, _
                    Optional qry As String = vbNullString, _
                    Optional complain As Boolean = True, _
                    Optional sFix As String = vbNullString _
                    ) As cJobject
```

I have no idea why though...it works fine if you remove PtrSafe. Any ideas?

Comment: You dont put `PtrSafe` on your own functions or subs, only on those imported from the windows API's or DLL's.

Answer (score 2):

You should only need to use the "Declare" statement when you declare a reference to an external procedure in a dynamic-link library (DLL). It is always recommended that you use the PtrSafe keyword when doing this. Like [A.S.H.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4926357/a-s-h) said, you don't need to do this for your own functions. See this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278581.aspx) for more info.

Here is an example from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278581.aspx) of the correct syntax for using PtrSafe. It includes conditional compilation syntax, which might be useful in your situation:

```
Declare PtrSafe Function GetActiveWindow Lib "User32" () As LongPtr 
        #If Vba7 Then 
             ' Code is running in  32-bit or 64-bit VBA7. 
             #If Win64 Then 
                  ' Code is running in 64-bit VBA7. 
             #Else 
                  ' Code is not running in 64-bit VBA7. 
             #End If 
        #Else 
             ' Code is NOT running in 32-bit or 64-bit VBA7. 
        #End If
```

Comment: There is no `End Function` for Declare statements

Comment: And the Declare statements should be inside the conditional directives blocks.

Comment: Good call. I took out the end function statement. I suppose you could put the declare statement in the conditional blocks, but why would that be necessary?

Comment: The objective of the conditional blocks is to separate the declarations according to when they are needed. So in the VB7 part, you will use the declaration for the office 64 calls (with PtrSafe and so one), while in the else branch you will declare the same function without the PtrSafe (because if not the code won't work on old Office 32 bits).

Comment: For example code with PtrSafe won't work on Office 2007, so if you need to support old versions of office you need to use this kind of structure.