# How to run JSON parser in x64 Excel

Tags: json, vba, vba7

I've inherited VBA code that in part uses Codo's code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627652/parsing-json-in-excel-vba) (dated 9/4/2011).  It's been working beautifully for over 10 years in x32 Excel. However it does not work in x64 Excel. From reading lot's in forums and other places it looks like the ScriptEngine doesn't run in x64.

Can some one post code that modifies Codo's code so it runs in x64? I'm not looking to replace the code in it's entirety , only to add the necessary statements to get it to work in a x64  environment.
I believe that Declare statements using PtrSafe are needed but don't know where they would go or what additional parameters are needed.

I'm a newbie at this so please add helpful comments. Thank you so very much.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41224817/ptrsafe-vba-updating-an-excel-document-for-office-64-bit